# JQuery $('form').serialize() not working after $('div.container').load()

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, jquery-selectors

I've a page with a div that is updated via an AJAX call, like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="newinfo">
            <form id="selectform">
                Your name:<br>
                <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function reload_container() {
            $('#container').load('url/to/ajax/update');
            console.log($('#selectform').serialize());
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

The load response is identical (including the form id), but with differing contents.

If I run `reload_container();` from the debug console in Firefox however the `serialize()` function is empty, but `$('#selectform')` does is defined.

I need the contents of the form however. I do not know why the `$('#selectform')` selector does work after the reload but `serialize()` does not. Any help is much appreciated.

Please note that the inputs of the form do contain the name-tag. [jQuery serialize not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074627/jquery-serialize-not-working) is not relevant.

Update: events that are bound to elements in the container do not work either after the load(). E.g. `$('#newinfo').click(function(){alert('hi!'});` in the body load script. This is solved however by [jQuery .live() vs .on() method for adding a click event after loading dynamic html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht)

Comment: You want to serialize the result of the ajax request? And how do you call `reload_container()`?

Comment: You can define delegate events with `on( events, selector, handler )`

Comment: Yes I need to serialize, and reload_container is fired by a setInterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work fine. There is probably something wrong in your ajax handler. Hope this example helps you.
Also made an example with a delegated `input` event on the input element.

please provide your ajax handler if you need help with that.

```js
//define delegate event so it triggers after inserting new elements (with ajax) too.
$('#newinfo').on('input', 'input[name=firstname]', function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
});

//attach the reload_container function to the button for testing purpose
$('#reload').on('click', reload_container);

//This function mimics the result of your ajax request assuming you do something like this. It updates the form with a new form and run the serialize function on it.
function reload_container() {
  var ajaxResultMimic = '<form id="selectform">Your name:<br><input type="text" name="firstname" value="updated"><br></form>';
  $('#newinfo').html(ajaxResultMimic);
  console.log($('#selectform').serialize());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <button id="reload">reload</button>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="newinfo">
            <form id="selectform">
                Your name:<br>
                <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You're right, this does work fine. My problem must be unrelated to this. Thanks.

Comment: @L.A.Rabida Yeah I think you do something in your ajax handler that removes the `#selectform` element or removing the id of the element. Or not adding any inputs to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should execute your code inside the load complete handler.

```
$('#container').load('url/to/ajax/update', function() {
  console.log($('#selectform').serialize());
});
```

Check examples here http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but serialize() inside the load gives me the same result, serialize() still gives an empty result after a succesful load(). Besides, I do need serialize() later on when submitting the form in a get request.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use `serialize()` outside of the ajax handler.